# How can I set options in SConstruct for C compiler depending on compiler type?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, scons, compiler-options

I need to set additional options for C compiler, e.g. add flag to turn all warnings ON, depending on the type of the compiler. E.g. for MSVC I should use

```
env.Append(CPPFLAGS = "/Wall")
```

but for mingw (gcc) I need to use:

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS = "-Wall")
```

How can I do this in scons way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just check for the name of the compiler:

```
cc = env['CC']
if cc == 'cl':
  env.Append(CPPFLAGS = '/Wall')
elif cc == 'gcc':
  env.Append(CCFLAGS = '-Wall')
```