# Changing default C compiler in Linux, using SCons

Tags: c, gcc, scons

On my Linux platform, I have several versions of `gcc`.

Under `usr/bin` I have:

- `gcc34`
- `gcc44`
- `gcc`

Here are some outputs:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

$ gcc44 --version
gcc44 (GCC) 4.4.0 20090514 (Red Hat 4.4.0-6)
```

I need to use the 4.4 version of `gcc` however the default seems to the 4.1 one.

I there a way to replace `/usr/bin/gcc` and make `gcc44` the *default* compiler **not using a symlink** to `/usr/bin/gcc44` ?

The reason why I can't use a symlink is because my code will have to be shipped in a RPM package using `mock`. `mock` creates a minimal linux installation from scratch and just install the specified dependencies before compiling my code in it. I cannot customize this "minimal installation".

Ideally, the perfect solution would be to install an official RPM package that replaces `gcc` with `gcc44` as the *default* compiler. Is there such a package ? Is this even possible/good ?

#### Additional information

I have to use [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) (a `make` alternative) and **it doesn't** let me specify the binary to use for `gcc`.

I will also accept any answer that will tell me how to specify the `gcc` binary in my `SConstruct` file.

Comment: What linux distribution? Some have methods of selecting the default versions

Comment: If you need to use an entirely different compiler, not only a different version, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13161690/3052438

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. One way is to compile and install `gcc` from source.
2. See http://old.nabble.com/Choosing-compiler-td4675207.html

From that:

```
env = Environment()
env.Replace(CC = "my_cc_compiler")
```

Or, as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961164/how-can-i-set-options-in-sconstruct-for-c-compiler-depending-on-compiler-type,),

```
env['CC'] = 'gcc44'
```

Comment: cc=env['gcc44'] is incorrect.. env['CC']='gcc44' is correct. (though you likely need to do so for CXX, SHCC, SHCXX, SHLINK, LINK, etc.. See manpage for what those are all used for.

Answer (score 8):

This is a long way in the past now, but I just thought I'd add the solution I found, which doesn't require changing the SConscript file. It was useful for me as I need to build v8 under centos 5, so possibly it may be useful for someone else too.

```
CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44 scons
```

That's it!

Comment: Note that scons (unlike e.g. a typical autotools project) does not by default allow you to override the CC/CXX variables via the environment. The SConscript have to be specifically created to do so.

Comment: yes, to set CC and CXX scons should be called like, eg.: scons CXX=clang++ CC=clang target