# Cross-Compiling Swiften library for ARM-embedded with SCons makery

Tags: android, scons, swiften

Swiften is a XMPP client library and my objective was to build it for a ARM-embedded target running Linux.

I hacked my way to a *successful* cross-compile with little knowledge of SCons. I'll lay out my hack here with the hope that someone can point me to a maintainable solution using  the two makery files, `SConscript.boot` and `SConstruct`.

I had two tasks (neither accomplished satisfactorily):

1. Successfully switching the tool-chain from native-compile to cross-compile
2. Ensuring that OpenSSL libraries were successfully linked (not supplied by the [swiftim](https://swift.im/swiften/) project; they has to be installed and built in the `3rdParty` folder).

**Switching the tool-chain from native-compile to cross-compile for ARM**

My ARM cross tool-chain components, gcc, g++, ld, etc are located here.

```
/opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
```

I couldn't find a way to tell `scons` to use the cross tool-chain (from the above location) instead of the native tool (in the usual place, `/usr/bin`). Prefacing the invocation (`./scons Swiften`) with the fully-qualified values for the environment variables, CC and CXX  didn't work (while not recommended, its alluded to in [one place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944251/changing-default-compiler-in-linux-using-scons)).

Scons would *only* pick up the *native* tool-chain even after many ad hoc changes to the makery.

So, as a *hack*, I *had* to change the native tool-chain to point to the cross tool-chain.

```
/usr/bin/gcc -> /opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7.3*
/usr/bin/g++ -> /opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++*
```

The first compile-break for ARM was fixed by adding the line below to the default portion of the build script, `SConscript.boot`.

```
env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ["_LITTLE_ENDIAN"])
```

The next compile-break has to do with the OpenSSL header files not being found. To fix the location issue, I had to introduce the line below into SConscript.boot

```
vars.Add(PackageVariable("openssl", "OpenSSL location", "/home/auro-tripathy/swiftim/swift/3rdParty/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1c/"))
```

**Linking with OpenSSL**

For the sample Switften programs to link with the OpenSSL libraries,  I had to move `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` (built separately) from the location they were built to the toolchain library-location like so.

```
mv ~/swiftim/swift/3rdParty/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1c/libcrypto.a /opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/.
```

**Help**

Not understanding of the working of scons, I've made some hacks to get it to work.

I’d like some help to:

1. Introduce a new target called ARM-embedded, just like other targets; iPhone, android, etc
2. Clean way to integrate OpenSSL into the build .

**Update**
Per dirkbaechle, retried the script below and it works

```
export CC=/opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/gcc
export CXX=/opt/toolchain/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/g++
./scons Swiften
```

Comment: The cross-compilation aspect of your question is already answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15206709/1158895

Answer (score 3):

Brady's answer is correct, regarding how you'd do it in plain SCons. I'd just like to mention that the top-level SConstruct of Swiften already provides arguments like "`cc=`" and "`cxx=`" for using local toolchains.
You might want to inspect the ouput of `scons -h` for a complete list of available options.

In addition, the SConscript for the OpenSSL build expects the sources to be located in the relative folder named "`openssl`", not "`openssl-1.0.1c`" as in your case. Maybe that's where your build problems are mainly coming from.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkbaechle. Taking a hint from you, I tried prefacing the CC and CXX with the tool-chain values and SCons picked up the right compiler. I'll try them as args a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

I left a comment above regarding the cross-compilation. Its already been answered in the link provided, but basically you just need to set the appropriate construction variables: CC, CXX, LINK, etc.

As for a "Clean way to integrate OpenSSL into the build" this can be performed simply by adding library and include paths appropriately as follows replacing the quoted values appropriately:
(without having to copy/move the original files)

```
# This sets the location of the OpenSSL Include paths
env.Append(CPPPATH="path/to/openssl/includes")

# This sets the location of the OpenSSL Libraries
env.Append(LIBPATH="path/to/openssl/libraries")

# These are the OpenSSL libraries to be linked into the binary
env.Append(LIBS=["OpenSSL_lib", "OpenSSL_lib2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of compiler, and additional flags, can all be set in Swift's config.py file. A snippet from config.py using a custom compiler and flags is below (the one I use on one of my dev boxes):

```
cc = link = "/usr/local/llvm-git/bin/clang"
cxx = "/usr/local/llvm-git/bin/clang++"

bothflags = " -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++"
cxxflags = bothflags + " -I/usr/local/libcxx/include -Wno-deprecated"
linkflags = bothflags + " -L/usr/local/libcxx/lib"
```

This should work for cross-compiling in the same manner.

To use a bundled openssl, you should just be able to extract into 3rdParty/OpenSSL, and add `openssl_force_bundled = True` to your config.py. You should not need to fiddle with setting include paths to this yourself. It's conceivable that this is tied to a particular openssl release as I've not compiled a bundled openssl since 1.0.0a, but if it doesn't work with the current version it's probably a bug that ought to be fixed. You could also cross-compile openssl yourself and use `openssl='/path/to/openssl'`, but that's a little more of a nuisance for you.